# Como faço para acessar os índices de um vetor retornado por um método em java?

Tags: java, array, return

Tenho um método chamado `vetorVoos` que retorna um vetor do tipo `NodeVoo` e quero acessar os índices desse vetor através do método em outra classe.

Este é o método:

```
public NodeVoo[] vetorVoos(){
    if(isEmpty()){
        return null;
    }
    NodeVoo vetor[] = new NodeVoo[size()],aux2 = inicio;
    for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
        vetor[i] = aux2;
        aux2 = aux2.proximo;
    }
    return vetor;
}
```

E já tentei pegar o índice do vetor das seguintes maneiras em outra classe:

```
vetorVoos()[1],
vetorVoos(1),
[1]vetorVoos()
```

Nada disso funcionou.

Comment: Tem certeza de que o índice 1 existe ou o retorno não foi `null`?

Comment: Esse indice usei apenas de exemplo, o meu problema é mais na sintaxe, pois o programa nem compila quando tento fazer assim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, armazena o retorno da função numa variável:

`NodeVoo[] voos = vetorVoos();`

e depois acessa os índices:

`NodeVoo voo = voos[1];`

Comment: Obrigado, deu acerto desta maneira.

Answer (score 0):

Crie uma classe `NodeVoo` que será o seu modelo de classe para uma lista futura:

**Classe NodeVoo (exemplo)**

```
public class NodeVoo {    
    private String descricao;
    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }
    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }    
}
```

---

Após a criação da classe `NodeVoo` crie uma lista de NodeVoo (`Array`) com o nome de `ListaVoo` como o código logo abaixo:

**Classe ListaVoo (exemplo)**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class ListaVoo {
    public ListaVoo(){
        this.nodeVoo = new ArrayList<>();
    }    
    public ListaVoo(List<NodeVoo> nodeVoo){
        this.nodeVoo = nodeVoo;
    }
    private List<NodeVoo> nodeVoo;
    public List<NodeVoo> getNodeVoo() {
        return nodeVoo;
    }
    public void setNodeVoo(List<NodeVoo> nodeVoo) {
        this.nodeVoo = nodeVoo;
    }    
    public void addVoo(NodeVoo nodeVoo){
        this.nodeVoo.add(nodeVoo);
    }    
}
```

**Utilizando**

```
    //Criando 2 instâncias da classe NodeVoo (Modelo)
    NodeVoo nodeVoo1 = new NodeVoo();
    NodeVoo nodeVoo2 = new NodeVoo();

    //Criando a lista de ListaVoo
    ListaVoo lista = new ListaVoo();

    //Adicionando na lista as duas classes NodeVoo
    lista.addVoo(nodeVoo1);
    lista.addVoo(nodeVoo2);

    //Resgatando a quantidade de itens na lista ListaVoo
    int quantidade = lista.getNodeVoo().size();
```

Todos os dados referentes são exemplos, mas, totalmente funcional.